# User error_handlers in app.yaml to return HTTP response

Tags: google-app-engine

To quote the documentation from [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) you can use `error_handlers` in your `app.yaml` to configure custom error pages that are returned for different error types. From the documentation there is only mention of `.html` files being used.

Is there a way to send an HTTP response instead of an HTML page?

As an example, the desired outcome can be achieved in nginx with something like the following:

```
server {
 error_page                            502 @bad_gateway;
 location @bad_gateway {
  return                               502 '{\n\t"success": false,\n\t"code": -1,\n\t"message": "Server is down",\n\t"status_code": 502,\n\t"status_message": "Bad Gateway",\n\t"detailed": ["Server is down"]\n}';
  add_header                           Content-Type "application/json charset=UTF-8" always;
  internal;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine uses the handler script that corresponds to the URL on the app.yaml configuration file when it receives a web request to your app. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled) is all the relevant information on how requests are handled on the Google App Engine standard environment. I would put this logic on the script file and send the HTTP response from there, since the error_handlers field is specifically used to configure custom error pages. Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) as a reference for your app.yaml file.

The error_handlers section exists to serve static files for the following specific error codes with App Engine: over_quota, dos_api_denial, and timeout. You can check that information on the documentation. You could serve for example an error.json file with all the structure provided on your Nginx example instead of a error.html file

Comment: Right, but for whatever reason if the app engine service isn't reachable, we won't be able to handle the logic within app engine. This is why the `error_handlers` section exists to begin with - to provide a way to have error pages when the app engine service isn't reachable. My question is rather than serving html, can we instead issue an http response (helpful for JSON APIs)

Comment: The error_handlers section exists to serve static files for the following specific error codes with App Engine: over_quota, dos_api_denial, and timeout. You can check that information on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#error_handlers). You could serve for example an error.json file with all the structure provided on your Nginx example instead of a error.html file.